# Microsoft Azure IoT Hub and connectionString without DeviceId

Tags: node.js, azure-iot-hub

I've got a connectionString from a third party to Microsoft Azure IoT Hub which doesn't contain a `DeviceId`.

I've tried to use this SDK, but it requires a `DeviceId`:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-iot-device-http

Can one use Azure IoT Hub without `DeviceId` ?

Comment: does it happen to be the connection string of the iothubowner? (or another service-side access policy)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work as a IOT hub. Basically from the connection string which we get it from Azure portal doesn't include device id.

Sample for initializing a client and creation of device.

```
var iothub = require('azure-iothub');

var connectionString = '[IoT Connection String]';

var registry = iothub.Registry.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

// Create a new device
var device = {
deviceId: 'sample-device-' + Date.now()
};

registry.create(device, function(err, deviceInfo, res) {
    if (err) console.log(op + ' error: ' + err.toString());
    if (res) console.log(op + ' status: ' + res.statusCode + ' ' + res.statusMessage);
    if (deviceInfo) console.log(op + ' device info: ' + JSON.stringify(deviceInfo));
});
```

You can find more samples here.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/tree/master/service

hope it helps.